# Call a hidden shell script file in .bashrc file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I've created a shell script and placed in home directory. but to make it invisible I put a DOT  before it's name. I mean `.filename.sh`. Now I want to call this file through `.bashrc` file which is also invisible and placed in home directory.

I tried

`sh .filename.sh` and 
`sh filename.sh` both but no success.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

. filename.sh   #I'm trying to call this script here at the beginning of the file

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
...
...  #some more content in .bashrc file
...
```

this shell script will print something on terminal whenever we open new tab or window in terminal.

EDIT:
I tried `. .filename.sh` but it works only when we are in home directory I mean (`user@user$`)
but it should work for all directory, I mean no matter where am I (for instance suppose I'm in Desktop `user@user:~/Desktop$`) and now if I open a new tab it shows error. It should work because when I put same content directly in .bashrc file instead of calling this sh file then it works well for all directory .

Comment: `. filename.sh` should work

Comment: is there a space between DOT and filename.sh

Comment: definitely YES... Can you try?

Comment: From the command line, run .bashrc.  What, __precisely__, is the error message that you see?  If there is no error message, then bash found and ran the file successfully.

Comment: `. filename.sh` --> `. .filename.sh`

Comment: `. yourextraprofilefilepath` should work and it should have proper read permissions `. /usr/tmp/dummy.profile` in my case will be added to .profile file

Comment: @realspirituals what? I didn't get it.

Comment: That means that bash did not find a file with that name.  What does `ls -alt .filename.sh` show?  (If you are not in the home directory when running these commands, switch there first.)

Comment: @John1024  `-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 901 Mar 20 12:24 .filename.sh
`

Comment: @user3359876 so what you get error like `bash: filename.sh: No such file or directory`? Or something other means not get print from `filename.sh`? if yes then show `filename.sh`.

Comment: Under what circumstances are you trying to source `.bashrc` when the working directory *isn't* your home directory?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to source a file you can use two different notations. You could write

```
source path/to/filename
```

but you could also write

```
. path/to/filename
```

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> ". filename [arguments] ... This builtin is equivalent to source."

Maybe in your case you are confused by the dot-notation. By prefixing your file with a dot you made it a hidden file. That means what you need is a second dot in front of your filename or just use the `source` command which is in my opinion the better notation and harder to miss. :)
Also to be on the safe side you should include a path and use quotes in case you have characters in your filename that have to be escaped normally.

As a result the following should do it considering your file exists in the root of your home directory. I added a test to check for its existence:

```
import="~/.filename.sh"

if [[ -f "$import" ]]; then
    source "$import"
else
    echo "Could not source ${import}. File does not exist."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following if .bashrc and the the script are in the same directory

```
. ./.filename.sh
```

Or use this if the script is present in the home directory

```
. ~/.filename.sh
```

Comment: both do not work, it returns ". is a directory"